# mysql / mariadb - remove ipv6 user

Tags: centos, mysql, mariadb

Can I remove the 'user'@'::1' <- ipv6 user from mariadb?

I have ipv6 disabled on my CentOs install.

Or is it not related to ipv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove any unused account except `root@localhost` that should have proper non-empty password.

Default accounts are created to ensure that you can initially log into the mysql in the most cases, even on the pure IPv6 hosts.

Comment: ok, so the ::1 user (ipv6) is unused?

Comment: because the 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' will be used,

Comment: Yep. Even `root@%` is excessive as far as connection via ssh-forwarded port is way more secure.